# The line graph of Eulerian and Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path, graph-connectivity

If a graph $G$ is Eulerian then I can show that  the line graph of $G$ is Eulerian but is the converse true ?

If $G$ is Hamiltonian then I can show that the line graph of $ G$ is Hamiltonian but is it Hamiltonian connected ?

If $G$ contains a dominating circuit then the line graph of $G$ is Hamiltonian but does it contain a dominating circuit ?

Comment: what are your thoughts on these problems? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, because line graph $L(K_4)$ of graph $K_4$ is connected and $4$-regular, therefore is Eulerian, but $K_4$ is not Eulerian.
2. No, because $C_5$ is Hamiltonian, but $L(C_5) \cong C_5$ is not Hamilton-connected.
3. Yes. Hamiltonian cycle of graph $H$ obviously is a dominating circuit in $H$, independently of whether $H$ is a line graph of some graph or not.